# normal user to rsync between two systems as root

Tags: linux, permissions, rsync, root

How can I change the user permissions so that the user will be able to rsync between two systems as a root.

I added the user in visudo.

> paru ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/rsync

then I typed the rsync command in 1 system to push data from one server to another

> rsync -avP /opt/paru/ paru@105.1.167.412:/opt/paru

when I rsync, it gives me the following error:

> sending incremental file list rsync: mkdir "/opt/paru" failed:
>   Permission denied (13) rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at
>   main.c(576) [receiver=3.0.6] rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (9
>   bytes received so far) [sender] rsync error: error in rsync protocol
>   data stream (code 12) at io.c(600) [sender=3.0.6]

What should I do so that user paru can rsync between the two systems as a root?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to actually connect to the remote system as root.

Don't use password-authentication for that, so make sure the `sshd_config` on the target machine is set to `PermitRootLogin without-password`. Then, on the remote system add an ssh key to root's authorized_keys file. Load that ssh-key into the local user's ssh-agent.

Then you can simply rsync like this:

```
rsync -avP /opt/paru/ root@105.1.167.412:/opt/paru
```

There's no security benefit to your using `sudo` over the root account, since the `paru` user on the remote system can easily exploit their sudo permissions to elevate to root anyway.

Another method, that *does* use `sudo` is [described here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92125/20502). I've always preferred the above method though, for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem trying to backup to rsync.net.  They told me that the last part, after the colon ":", should be a local pathname.

> rsync -avP /opt/paru/ paru@105.1.167.412:/opt/paru

becomes

> rsync -avP /opt/paru/ paru@105.1.167.412:opt/paru